# the first human beings "to live" or "lived"?

Tags: grammar

I am confused why does below sentence use "to live" which implies a future state as far as I know.

“The first human beings to live in the Americas came from Asia more than 15,000 years ago.”

Answer (score 4):

In this sentence "to live" is an infinitive being used as an adjective. The infinitive does not indicate any particular tense, but to the *concept* of living (used as another part of speech). The adjective infinitive phrase "to live in the Americas" is a modifier of "human beings" in this case.

From the [Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Infinitives.htm):

> "Infinitives are used to express an action as a concept, rather than what is being done or performed by the subject of a clause. In this way, they can function as nouns, adjectives, or adverbs—that is, nearly any role in a sentence except that of a main verb.
>
> Infinitives can stand on their own to complete these functions, or they can work together with their own predicates (any additional information that modifies or completes them) to form infinitive phrases. Infinitive phrases function as a nouns, adjectives, or adverbs as a single, holistic unit."

Comment: Adjective is a category (parts of speech) and not a function.

Comment: Adjective is a part of speech, but it *is* also a function in that other words and phrases can be used in the place of an adjective, as in this case. I'm not sure what you're trying to say or how it helps answer the question.

Comment: HI geekahedron, thanks for your reply. In this case, can I use "lived" or "living" to replace "to live" for a modifier?

Comment: @geekahedron my point is an adjective can be used as many ways. These ways are called functions. So when you say that a particular word is used as an adjective, it doesn't say explicitly what way that is used or more precisely what function that word play there. Well, an word or phrase can however be placed in place of an adjective. And an adjective is not a function. My whole point is that please keep the category and function apart. Don't mix it up. It's not good for learners and future readers and not for the OP as well. You however can do some more research before editing your answer.

Comment: @Man_From_India 
HI Man_From_India, thanks for your reply. In this case, can I use "lived" or "living" to replace "to live" for a modifier?

Comment: @Man_From_India The terms "function" and "category" are your additions, not part of my answer. To say that the infinitive is being used as an adjective is perfectly correct, as is such use of the infinitive "to live" in this example. Making argumentative statements of opinion -- without any research of your own -- is wholly unconstructive and, again, I'm not sure how it helps answer the question.

Comment: @geekahedron let's take this analogy. It's a bold one :) consider a paper (think that it's a category) and it came be used either as a wrapper or something to put the words down. These uses are called functions of the paper. Now the category or parts of speech is adjective. It can be used either a modifier or a complement. The use of adjective as a complement or a modifier is its function. So if we say something used used as an adjective (category) we can think that it can be used either as a modifier or a complement or both. It is not very clear, right. Even sometimes this is wrong.

Comment: @Man_From_India Your analogy is more broken than it is bold. What does that have to do with this answer? If we accept the analogy, however, adjective is both a category ("blue is an adjective") *and* a function ("In the phrase 'microwave oven,' the noun 'microwave' is being used as an adjective").

Comment: For example if something is used in a a sentence as a modifier and not a complement, and we say that it is used as an adjective, one might think that it is used as a complement. So it is wrong to say it that way. I hope I could make it clear :)

Comment: @Man_From_India Sorry, but it is not wrong to say that a phrase or a word that is normally a different part of speech are being used as an adjective. It's a very normal usage, in fact, and more specific than simply saying "modifier" which can refer to either adjective phrases or adverbial phrases, for example. Do you have any source which backs up the distinction you are drawing or your claim that my terminology is incorrect? Nearly if not every dictionary and grammar resource uses that type of phrasing ubiquitously.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93777/discussion-between-geekahedron-and-man-from-india).

Comment: @geekahedron yes I do have. But you actually answered your own question. See, a modifier can be an adjective or an adverb. Or anything else. So if you say the noun phrase "this way" is used as an adjective in "he did it this way", will it say that this noun phrase is actually a modifier? I don't think so. And it is a noun phrase and not a adjective. So this noun phrase is used as a modifier there. This is much clear statement.

Answer (score 0):

> **1.** **The first police to arrive** neglected to cordon off the gas station, where broken glass and blood stains lay everywhere. Police allowed reporters and photographers to walk around inside, contaminating the crime scene.
>
> **2.** I'm waiting for **the police to arrive**.

Consider the sentences above, specifically the Noun Phrase (NP) *the first police to arrive* in sentence #1 and *the police to arrive* in sentence #2.

The infinitive clause - *to arrive* - in both the cases instills two different meaning. In the first case the police has already arrived but in the second case the police is yet to arrive.

From your quoted sentence too we can derive such meaning -

> **The first human beings to live in the Americas** came from Asia more than 15,000 years ago

The meaning is *the first human beings who lived in America came from Asia more than 15000 years ago*.

As a side note (because you asked in comments), you can write the following sentences -

> **The first human beings lived in the Americas** came from Asia more than 15,000 years ago. (Doubtful acceptability)
>
> **The first human beings living in the Americas** came from Asia more than 15,000 years ago.

**Reference Note:** 
On page 1265 Quirk et al in The Comprehensive English Grammar marked the sentence *The train arrived at platform 1 is from York.* as *"tending to unacceptability but not fully unacceptable"*.